# How to select attributes by unicode field value?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, select, select-by-attribute

I have an attribute table in QGIS 2.10 with a string field (myfield) and when I want to make a selection based on the unique values of this field I get no selection at all.

```
>idxmyfield = mylayer.fieldNameIndex("myfield")
>uniquevalues = mylayer.uniqueValues(idxmyfield)
>uniquevalues
>[u'avalue', u'bvalue']
>type(uniquevalues[0])
><type 'unicode'>

>y = len(uniquevalues)
>for x in range(y):
     it = mylayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression  (u' "myfield" = {0}'.format(uniquevalues[x])))
     mylayer.setSelectedFeatures([f.id() for f in it])
     selection = mylayer.selectedFeatures()
```

If I use another field with integer values the code is working. But if the values of the field are unicode/string it is not selecting anything.

So the type unicode differs from string or is it a type of string? If so, how can I change the type from unicode to string? Or how do I need to change the expression in order to get the selection I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a unicode string to a string this way:

```
s = u'UNICODE'
type(s)
<type 'unicode'>
t = str(s)
type(t)
<type 'str'>
```

But another issue is, that you missed the single quotes around your conditional argument when it is a string. When your condition is of type string you have to format the filter expression as following:

```
setFilterExpression(u' "myfield" = \'{0}\''.format(myfield[x]))
```

Remember: to enclose the single quote character in a single quoted string you must escape it.

```
>>> print ' "fieldname in double quotes" = \'condition in single quotes\' '
"fieldname in double quotes" = 'condition in single quotes'
```